# how do i place two apache virtualhosts with mod_wsgi and python in the httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

im trying to get two apache virtual hosts working with mod_wsgi and python, i want to access the two sites in different folders: ie example.com/sh  and example.com/th 
this is what i tried:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/moin-wsg

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sth@domain.com
    serverName  sub.example.com
    serverAlias www.sub.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /sh   /opt/source/sh/moin.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess  sh  user=th group=apache threads=5    python-path=/opt/source/sh/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup sh
    ErrorLog logs/sh.foo.info-error_log
    CustomLog logs/sh.foo.info-access_log common
<Location /sh>
    WSGIProcessGroup sh
</Location>
<Directory /opt/source/sh>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/th
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@domain.com
    serverName  sub.example.com
    serverAlias www.sub.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /site1   /opt/source/th/moin.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess  th  user=th group=apache threads=5    python-path=/opt/source/th/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    ErrorLog logs/th.foo.info-error_log
    CustomLog logs/th.foo.info-access_log common
<Location /th>
    WSGIProcessGroup th
</Location>
<Directory /opt/source/th/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

at this time only the first site works the second gives a 404 not found, how do i fix that? 
the two sites are both python based wiki's

Comment: The two sites must have different values for ServerName/ServerAlias. If you want each application to run under the same host, don't use two VirtualHost definitions, use one and put the configuration for both in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like Dumpleton says, 
this is how i ended up doing it:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/moin-wsg

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sth@domain.com
    serverName  sub.example.com
    serverAlias www.sub.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /sh   /opt/source/sh/moin.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess  sh  user=th group=apache threads=5    python-path=/opt/source/sh/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup sh
    ErrorLog logs/sh.foo.info-error_log
    CustomLog logs/sh.foo.info-access_log common
<Location /sh>
    WSGIProcessGroup sh
</Location>
<Directory /opt/source/sh>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias /site1   /opt/source/th/moin.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess  th  user=th group=apache threads=5    python-path=/opt/source/th/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    ErrorLog logs/th.foo.info-error_log
    CustomLog logs/th.foo.info-access_log common
<Location /th>
    WSGIProcessGroup th
</Location>
<Directory /opt/source/th/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```